# How to display all data from 2 related tables in a dbgrid with sql

Tags: delphi

I'm new to delphi and have created an SQL query which displays the results of a search entered by the user through an edit box (showing data from 2 related tables) in a dbGrid. 
The dbgrid displays no data until a search has been made and then the results of that search are displayed, however i was wondering whether it was possible to show all the related data in the dbgrid as if it were a table and the search then simply selects from it?
thanks

Comment: You can select the data and use Filter on that DataSet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could display all the data in the table. Then write an onExit event handler for your edit box which would look something like this (assuming that the string which you are entering in the edit box is supposed to match the value in the 'name' field of the query)

```
query.locate ('name', edit1.text, [loPartialValue]);
```

This will cause the dbgrid's cursor to jump to the first line which matches the string in the edit box.

Instead of using the OnExit event, you could also use the OnChange event of the edit box, but this would mean a search after every key stroke.

Your question was a bit vague so it's difficult to give a specific answer.